# Prime number checker returning every number as prime

Tags: vb.net

I have some code that is supposed to check if a number is prime or not but it is saying that every number above 2 is prime or it just won't work sometimes. I can't figure put what's wrong with my code. I'll post what I have so far.

```
    Dim intNumber As Integer = Me.txtNumber.Text
    Dim i As Integer
    Select Case intNumber
        Case Is < 2
            Me.lblAnswer.Text = intNumber & " is not prime."
        Case Is = 2
            Me.lblAnswer.Text = intNumber & " is prime."
        Case Is > 2
            For i = 3 To (intNumber - 1)
                If intNumber Mod i = 0 Then
                    Me.lblAnswer.Text = intNumber & " is not prime."
                Else
                    Me.lblAnswer.Text = intNumber & " is prime."
                End If
            Next i
    End Select
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `intNumber Mod i = 0` does not mean that a number is prime or not. However, when all of conditions `intNumber Mod i <> 0` are met, the number is prime. In other words, if at least one of `intNumber Mod i = 0`, the number is NOT prime. Another thought - you don't need a select case there. Generic prime searching for loop will work, there are no special conditions used for calculation. Out of curiosity, is it a project euler related question? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not returning after you find a number is not prime. So it checks all the way until i-1 and checks if i-1 Mod i = 0 which it never will be. So it says all numbers are prime.

Also, you only have to check if the prime numbers from 2 to sqrt(i) divide into i to see if i is a prime number or not.